# want to merge two tables as on table

Tags: php, mysql

I want all rows from this table

[image: module table]

The query of that db is

```
function getmodules(){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM module
    WHERE status=1";            
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query;
}
```

and selected rows from this one as query written

[image: permissions table]

the query for above db is

```
function getmoduledtls($id){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM module m
    INNER JOIN permissions p
    ON p.moduleId=m.moduleId
    WHERE m.status=1
    AND p.roleId='$id'";                        
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: What is what you need?

Comment: Expected Result?

Comment: i need result like `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [moduleId] => 1 [moduleName] => Course [status] => 1 [permissionId] => 24 [roleId] => 1 [view] => 1 [add] => 0 [edit] => 1 [deleteRole] => 0 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [moduleId] => 2 [moduleName] => Roles [status] => 1 [permissionId] => 37 [roleId] => 1 [view] => 0 [add] => 1 [edit] => 0 [deleteRole] => 0 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [moduleId] => 3 [moduleName] => Transactions [status] => 1 [permissionId] =>  [roleId] => 1 [view] => 0 [add] => 0 [edit] => 0 [deleteRole] => 0 ) )`

Answer (score 0):

You can select all fields for a table by using it's alias ie: m.* then select the individual fields from p that you want. Please note if any column in m and p have the same names the values from p will be returned. You will need to give any duplicate fields alias like

```
'm.status as module_status, p.status as permission_status"

SELECT m.*, p.permissionId, p.view, p.etc FROM module m
    INNER JOIN permissions p
    ON p.moduleId=m.moduleId
    WHERE m.status=1
    AND p.roleId='$id'"
```

Also please note this query is open to SQL injection. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)